# initialise all values in a query to 0 and top to NULL if there's no result

Tags: mysql, sql, database

Hi all i execute this query to get a table where there's statistics of some database information.. i'd like to intialise the fields that don't exist ( because the query is executed in different dates  and sometimes there's a day where there's nothing ) so i'd like it to return 0 and NULL ( in TOP column )

---

```
SELECT
  SUM(IF(`TOP` = 'one',`Nb`,0)) as first_one,
  SUM(IF(`TOP` = 'two',`Nb`,0)) as second_one,
  SUM(IF(`TOP` = 'three',`Nb`,0)) as thrid_one,
  SUM(IF(`TOP` NOT IN ('three','two','one'),`Nb`,0)) as forth_one,
  GROUP_CONCAT(IF(`TOP` NOT IN ('three','two','one'),`TOP`,'') SEPARATOR '') as `OR`
FROM (
    SELECT 
        COUNT(*) as Nb,
        'one' as `TOP` 
    FROM 
        mytable 
    WHERE 
        TYPE = 'MSS' 
        AND YEAR(date) = YEAR(CURDATE()) 
        AND MONTH(date) = MONTH(CURDATE()) 
    UNION ALL
    SELECT 
        COUNT(*) as Nb,
        'two' as `TOP` 
    FROM 
        mytable 
    WHERE 
        TYPE = 'MSS' 
        AND S=0
        AND YEAR(date) = YEAR(CURDATE()) 
        AND MONTH(date) = MONTH(CURDATE()) 
    UNION ALL
    SELECT 
        COUNT(*) as Nb,
        'three' as `TOP` 
    FROM 
        mytable 
    WHERE 
        TYPE = 'MSS' 
        AND S<>0
        AND YEAR(date) = YEAR(CURDATE()) 
        AND MONTH(date) = MONTH(CURDATE()) 
    UNION ALL
    SELECT
      `Nb`,
      `TOP`
    FROM(
      SELECT 
        COUNT(*) as Nb ,
        `OR` as `TOP` 
      FROM 
        mytable 
      WHERE 
        TYPE = 'MSS'  
        AND YEAR(date) = YEAR(CURDATE()) 
        AND MONTH(date) = MONTH(CURDATE()) 
      GROUP BY 
        `OR` 
      ORDER BY 
         Nb DESC 
      LIMIT 1
    ) as tmp
)as tmp1
```

Comment: Do you have a calendar table of all dates that you are interested in?

Comment: I have a datepicker to choose the date the query i modified it to make the date between two dates

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that in `tmp1` you have data you need but with "gaps" (days when there were no data at all) you could `RIGHT JOIN` tmp1 to table `tmp2` using `day` (I assume that you have such column in `tmp1` table). So `tmp2` would be just list of days:

```
SELECT '2013-05-17' as day UNION SELECT '2013-05-18' UNION SELECT ...
```

I could elaborate my answer if you'd like to provide your DB schema.

Comment: CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `mytable` (
  `id` smallint(5) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `FS` tinyint(4) NOT NULL,
  `ST` tinyint(3) NOT NULL,
  `DATE` datetime NOT NULL,
  `OR` varchar(60) NOT NULL,
  `T_OR` varchar(10) NOT NULL,
  `DEST` varchar(60) NOT NULL,
  `T_DEST` varchar(10) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`,`DATE`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;

Comment: @KirkERW: The set of columns in the posted schema doesn't exactly match the query, i.e. your query is referencing columns absent from the CREATE TABLE statement. Anyway, it might be a good idea to update *your question* with the schema instead of just replying in a comment.

Answer (score 0):

You can replace each subquery with:

```
SELECT
    IFNULL(tmp.Nb,0) as Nb,
    IFNULL(tmp.`TOP`, 'value') as `TOP`
FROM (    
   --subquery
) as tmp
```

Example for the first subquery:

```
SELECT
    IFNULL(tmp.Nb,0) as Nb,
    IFNULL(tmp.`TOP`, 'one') as `TOP`
FROM (    
    SELECT 
        COUNT(*) as Nb,
        'one' as `TOP` 
    FROM 
        mytable 
    WHERE 
        TYPE = 'MSS' 
        AND YEAR(date) = YEAR(CURDATE()) 
        AND MONTH(date) = MONTH(CURDATE()) 
) as tmp
```

Comment: In MySQL, if there's an aggregate function in SELECT and no GROUP BY, there will *always* be a result, and it will be exactly one row. The OP's query is just like that and so it should be enough to only add IFNULLs to the outer SELECT clause, specifically around the SUMs.

Comment: @AndriyM ur right, thanks , i missed that . It should also work if i add `IFNULL(tmp.TOP,'one')`

Answer (score 0):

SQL is good at grouping existing entities into categories, but bad at "creating" entities itself. I would advise either a generic number table (really just the numbers from 0 to a few hundredthousand) if you have also non-date categories or as Wiktor suggested a date-Table which gets filled every now and then and has the next few years as well as the time since your program is working.

With a date table

```
list_dates (
     id int(11) not null primary key auto_increment, 
     dateval date not null
)
```

you could start your queries from that table (with a reasonable range, of course) and count every thing else:

```
select list_dates.dateval as date, count(*) as cnt
from list_dates
left join actions on actions.actiontime >= (cast list_dates.date_val as datetime) 
     and actions.actiontime < (cast list_dates.date_val `interval 1 day as datetime) 
where list_dates.dateval between '$fromDate' and '$toDate'
group by list_dates.dateval
;
```

or starting with a number table numbers

```
select $fromDate + interval numbers.number day as date, count(*) as cnt
from numbers
left join actions 
on actions.actiontime >= (cast $fromDate + interval numbers.number day  as datetime) 
   and actions.actiontime < (cast $fromDate + interval (1 + numbers.number) day as datetime) 
where numbers.number >= 0 and numbers.number < $countDates
group by numbers.number
;
```

### One Day

If you really want just that one day (today) then you can of course use a anonymous subselect- Table instead, so it becomes

```
select list_dates.dateval as date, count(*) as cnt
from ( select curdate() as dateval ) as list_dates
left join actions on actions.actiontime >= (cast list_dates.date_val as datetime) 
     and actions.actiontime < (cast list_dates.date_val `interval 1 day as datetime) 
where list_dates.dateval between '$fromDate' and '$toDate'
group by list_dates.dateval
;
```

Comment: 'is filled every now and then' is not necessary. Simply create such a table once with dates from 1900 to 2500 (or whatever your maximum date range is). You can also add information such as 'isWorkingDay', 'IsHoliday' and grouping information such as 'MonthAndYear' etc. Just google for 'date dimension table' and you will even find ready-to-import-samples.